Importance of operator ordering in QFT field mode expansion
I have been going through some QFT textbooks (mostly Peskin and Schroeder's), and it is very common to find this situation when expanding the field modes (I'm using the complex Klein-Gordon field as an example)
$$H=\int d^3x E_p (a_p ^\dagger a_p+ b_pb_p^\dagger)$$
However, the textbooks express the final result as:
$$H=\int d^3x E_p (a_p ^\dagger a_p+ b_p^\dagger b_p+[b_p,b_p^\dagger])$$
I understand how to do this, and that we can draw meaningful insight from the additional term. But other than that, why bother doing this extra step? Is anything inherently wrong with the first form?

What do you mean "inherently wrong?" Is it inherently wrong to write an expression that doesn't equal a constant plus an operator that manifestly annihilates the ground state? I guess I would say it is not inherently wrong, but just less simple to work with. Anyways, the reason we prefer the latter expression is because we can drop the constant term and then we have a Hamiltonian that manifestly annihilates the ground state. In my opinion, it is not "inherently wrong" to write the operator in some other form, but it is less easy to work with in practice...

The renormalized Klein-Gordon theory has the "normal ordering", i.e.$$H=\int d^3p;(a_p^\dagger a_p+b_p^\dagger b_p).$$

The two expressions are equal:
$$
bb^\dagger = b^\dagger b+ [b,b^\dagger].
$$
The second is more useful, though, as the eigenvalues of $b^\dagger b$, being the mode occupation numbers, are easier to grasp that those of $bb^\dagger$. The $[b,b^\dagger]= 2E_p(2\pi)^3\delta^3(0)$ is a divergent $c$-number that is usually discarded by normal ordering.
Note the integration measure  should be
$$
\int\frac{d^3p}{2E_p(2\pi)^3}\cdots 
$$
rather than $d^3x$.

If you try to find the expectation value $<0|H|0>$ in the vaccum state|0> where $a_p|0>=0$, you will get an undefined value.
As $[a,a^+]$ =$\delta^3(0)$ and integrating it will give infinity <0|H|0>=$\delta^3(0) \int d^3p E_p$, where each p represents one oscillator , so integrating over the range$(-\infty,\infty)$ will give the result undefined.
$[a,a^+]$ is defined as the new zero of the energy scale.
Therefore we normalize the operators in order to avoid the infinity and get rid of it by defining it as 0 of energy scale and calculate expectation values with respect to it.
